# How to disable expandablelistview vertical scrolling when webview is scrolled horizontally

Tags: android, webview, scroll, expandablelistview, smoothing

I have taken a webview as a child in my expandable list. When I scroll the webview horizontally it clashes with vertical scroll of listview.

I want to smoothly scroll horizontally when swiped left or right.